# Erro, Não consigo salvar no banco usando hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, session, maven

Boa tarde Pessoa, preciso da ajuda de vocês! estou com um problema no meu projeto, o meu hibernate está funcionando a criação de tabelas mas quando fiz teste para tentar salvar não funciona e aparece o seguinte erro no jUnit( **org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: br.com.loja.domain.Fabricante** ).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: Meu Erro]

Estou usando maven, vou postar minhas classes aqui e minhas dependências!!

```
package br.com.loja.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="db_fabricante") 
public class Fabricante {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // AutoIncremento
@Column(name = "fabricanteID")
private Long codigo;


@Column(length = 50)
private String descricao;



public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}



public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

}
```

---

```
package br.com.loja.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;       
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

}
```

---

```
package br.com.loja.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import br.com.loja.domain.Fabricante;
import br.com.loja.util.HibernateUtil;

public class FabricanteDAO {
public void salvar(Fabricante fabricante){
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = null;

    try {
        transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
        sessao.save(fabricante);
        transacao.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        if(transacao != null){
            transacao.rollback();
        }
        throw ex;

    }finally{
        sessao.close();
    }


}




}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_loja</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">123456</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup,*** depois validate-->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

    <mapping class="br.com.loja.domain.Fabricante"/>
    <mapping class="br.com.loja.domain.Funcionario" />
    <mapping class="br.com.loja.domain.Produto" />
    <mapping class="br.com.loja.domain.Cliente" />
    <mapping class="br.com.loja.domain.PessoaFisica" />
    <mapping class="br.com.loja.domain.PessoaJuridica" />
    <mapping class="br.com.loja.domain.Venda" />
    <mapping class="br.com.loja.domain.Itens" />

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

```
package br.com.loja.test;

import org.junit.Test;

import br.com.loja.dao.FabricanteDAO;
import br.com.loja.domain.Fabricante;

public class FabricanteDAOTest {
@Test
public void salvar(){
    Fabricante f1 = new Fabricante();
    f1.setDescricao("Gedore");

    Fabricante f2 = new Fabricante();
    f2.setDescricao("Robust");

    FabricanteDAO dao = new FabricanteDAO();
    dao.salvar(f1);
    dao.salvar(f2);
}
}
```

---

Estou usado Maven, segue minhas dependencias

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ferreira</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjetoLoja</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>javassist</groupId>
<artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
<version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}                </outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando esse arquétipo do Maven será necessário criar o arquivo `hibernate.cfg.xml` dentro da pasta resources de testes (src/test/resources). Isso ocorre pois o contexto de carregamento dos arquivos de recurso é diferente entre o `test` e o `main`. É só copiar e colar o mesmo arquivo que já está em `src/main/resources` em `src/test/resources` que vai funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado Giuliana, funciono!

Comment: Ótimo! Marca como respondida :)